# Convert DLL to Resx and Vice Versa

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have an ASP NET MVC Web Application.
I currently have set the resources for the main and the secondary language, and i have deployed the project.

My customer needs to edit these resources files whenever he wants. So he wants to edit the DLL's which represent the RESX files.

Can we somehow convert dll to resx , edit and then, back to DLL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the tool named "dnSpy" it does what i want.